# Changing the Country & Region with Gift Card

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-id, accounts

You can assume that I am able to change Country & Region. I am trying to change my Country & Region to Germany, though i do not own a German debit Card to do the verification. I am currently living in Germany and I have a german phone number, i tried with that as well but it accepts only numbers from O2 mobile company which i dont have.

Am I able to change Country if I buy and use a German Gift Card? Or if I cant with that either any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, YES you can using a gift card bought in that country. Though you have to use a real address of that country for the process to finish.